# C# get child handles using FindWindowEx by name and ordinal number

Tags: c#, winapi, visual-c++, handle, spy++

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx I define FindWindowEx function.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string lclassName, string windowTitle);
```

Now I am able to find **first** handle of "Button" control (get name from Spy++) setting childAfter as **IntPtr.Zero**.

```
IntPtr hWndParent = new IntPtr(2032496);  // providing parent window handle
IntPtr hWndButton = FindWindowEx(hWndParent, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", string.Empty);
```

How to get **second**, **third** or any handle of "Button" control inside that parent window? The fact is, button titles may vary, so I cannot find them directly by name defining fourth parameter.

Comment: Please rephrase your question for us to understand.

Comment: Why not use the UIAutomation namespace?

Comment: My solution can be used for unmanaged C++ programs as well as snippet is quite the same :) This is for digging/hacking, not for testing purposes. Don't like any ready-to-use automations in researches.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
static IntPtr FindWindowByIndex(IntPtr hWndParent, int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
        return hWndParent;
    else
    {
        int ct = 0;
        IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
        do
        {
            result = FindWindowEx(hWndParent, result, "Button", null);
            if (result != IntPtr.Zero)
                ++ct;
        }
        while (ct < index && result != IntPtr.Zero);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Use like:

```
IntPtr hWndThirdButton = FindWindowByIndex(hWnd, 3); // handle of third "Button" as shown in Spy++
```