# C# Paste Data into ExternalProcess

Tags: c#, windows

I am writing a launcher in C# that processes user input and I would like its corresponding output string to be piped into an external program. The external program is a precompiled C# executable that is end-of-life, so I cannot easily modify it.

I can easily launch the desired program using ExternalProcess, but do not see any means for sending data over. My desired function calls go something like:

```
string myString = "string to pass over"
Clipboard.SetText(myString);

Process ExternalProcess = new Process();
ExternalProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Notepad.exe";
ExternalProcess.Start();

// some kind of paste command here...
// ExternalProcess.magicpaste(myString);

ExternalProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Is there a better way to go about this? I realize the purported security implication in piping text this way, but I need to create a simple launcher program to support a legacy project.

Comment: can you give more details on what the legacy program actually does.. as well as an example of the type of text that's being passed over.. it's a bit vague in regards to what you have posted so once Notepad.exe has started.. then in your case what do you expect to do once you close the file..

Comment: @MethodMan I quite literally just need to pass some plain text, hence the Notepad example. Basically I just need to autofill field in a form that is inside another program.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057063/how-to-pass-parameters-to-another-process-in-c-sharp and if that doesn't help do a simple google search search on the following `C# passing params to another process`

Comment: @MethodMan I am familiar with command line params, and would go that route if I could. Unfortunately that would be changing the code of the legacy program I am trying to make the launcher for. i.e. it is not expecting any params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your answer in the comments that you need to put some text in a field, I'm afraid you're going to have to get your hands dirty.

That text box (I assume that's what it is) in this legacy application, will be a window.  And you're going to have to find it, and send it a message using Platform-Invoke.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673099/c-sharp-get-child-handles-using-findwindowex-by-name-and-ordinal-number) should get you started.

If said control has a name, you can find it using [Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: Thanks that looks promising. I'll dig into that.