# How to listen for "Form.Shown" and "Window.Closing" for a form from a 3rd party DLL?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

My C# app calls into a 3rd party DLL. This DLL may or may not show a window (form). I wish to register for a callback / notification / event when this window is shown, and another when the window is closed (by the X or by the "Close" button). Bonus if I can tell the name of the button that caused the action (ie: I'll do something different if they press "Close" or "X", vs. if they press "Purchase")

I do not have access to the source code of this DLL, and the headers don't specify the forms.

Is what I'm needing even possible?

If you're wondering, it's for the [PaddleSDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Paddle.PaddleSDK)

Comment: You can use SetWinEventHook`, for example setting a callback for `EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED`, so when a Button is pressed (invoking its default action) `WinEventProc` will notify the `hWnd` and `ID` of the child control invoked. You can do all this, plus intercepting a Window creation/destruction, using UI Automation. The `WindowPatter.WindowOpened` and `WindowPatter.WindowClosed` events notify when (any) Window is opened/closed. Specific event can be rised for any of the Window child/descendant control (especially straightforward for a Windows Form, less for a WPF Window).

Comment: See here for a SeWinEventHook implementation [Move window when external application's window moves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812831/7444103) (you just need to change the events that are notified). [This is a base implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55028688/7444103) of a Window Watcher procedure using UI Automation; it shows how to detect a Window Opened event and interact with that Window.

Comment: for me, EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED never fires :(.  You seem to suggest two different methods: 1: SetWinEventHook() and 2: UI Automation.  they are not related, right? so which one?  I can't find any info on "WindowPatter.WindowOpened" do you mean pattern?  what i need to do is, when the window is first shown, hide a button (named "Enter License"), so it's gone (the user can't "tab" to it).  then, when the  window is closed via button called "Close" or via "X", i need to know.  (bonus if i can differentiate between that and the window just closing because the user otherwise completed their business)

Comment: if i do use UI Automation to catch the window showing, and find the button i want to hide, then how do i hide it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, mispelled it (or the Tablet did :) [WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowopenedevent), [WindowPattern.WindowClosedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowclosedevent). You can get any control in WinForms through UIAutomation. But the .Net implementation of the native UIA is, let's say, *partial*. Once you find the element you want (by name and `ControlType`, usually) you can call `ShowWindow([hWnd], SW_HIDE)` to hide the element.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook)

The internet is ***full of stupid ways*** to do this but this is the right way.  Polling is bad (m' kay?).

If you search StackOverflow for  [SetWinEventHook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SetWinEventHook)  and look for the c# hits, you will find lots of examples for use.

Comment: [looking here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/event-constants) i am unable to find events for "window opening" and "window closing", or "button pressed". i see "EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED" but that doesn't fire for the button in the window that comes up, nor the "X". i CAN get events for "front window changed" (EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND) but that says nothing about opening or closing. note the "EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART / END" events don't seem to be firing, presumably because the window is not a dialog. I've heard a suggestion to  use UI Automation, is that the better choice?

Answer (score 0):

Okay wow, this seems to be working: (thanks everyone for the hints!!)

```
    private int[]           i_checkoutWindID;

    private void    RegisterEventListener()
    {
        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
            WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
            AutomationElement.RootElement,
            TreeScope.Children,
            (sender, e) => 
        {
            AutomationElement       element = sender as AutomationElement;
            string                  automationID = element.Current.AutomationId;

            if (automationID != kLicenseWindowAutomationID) return;

            i_checkoutWindID = element.GetRuntimeId();

            AutomationElement licenseButton = element.FindFirst(
                TreeScope.Descendants,
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, kLicenseButtonAutomationID));

            if (licenseButton != null) {
                IntPtr      hwnd = new IntPtr(licenseButton.Current.NativeWindowHandle);
                Control     buttonRef = Control.FromHandle(hwnd);

                HideButton_Safe(buttonRef);
            }
        });

        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
            WindowPattern.WindowClosedEvent,
            AutomationElement.RootElement,
            TreeScope.Subtree,
            (sender, e) => 
        {
            WindowClosedEventArgs       args = e as WindowClosedEventArgs;

            if (Automation.Compare(args.GetRuntimeId(), i_checkoutWindID)) {
                Array.Clear(i_checkoutWindID, 0, i_checkoutWindID.Length);
                <do your "window closed" callback here>;
            }
        });
    }

    private void HideButton_Safe(Control buttonRef)
    {
        if (buttonRef.InvokeRequired) {
            var d = new SafeCallDelegate_ButtonHide(HideButton_Safe);
            buttonRef.Invoke(d, new object[] { buttonRef });
        } else {
            buttonRef.Hide();
        }
    }
```