# I cannot wait for calc.exe to exit but I can wait for mspaint.exe to exit. Why and how to wait for calc.exe to exit?

Tags: c#, process

When spawning `mspaint.exe` I can wait the process to exit before the main app closes.
But when I spawn `calc.exe` I cannot wait so the main app closes immediately.

Why does it happen and how to wait `calc.exe`?

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "mspaint.exe"; // try changing to calc.exe
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate this app!");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: The calculator is an UWP app. Means calc.exe is just a hosting executable that will start the actual calculator and then will end itself directly.

Comment: You can use UI Automation events to get notifications when a windowed Process shows its window (and / or that window is closed): `WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent` and `WindowPattern.WindowClosedEvent`. Simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58233065/7444103) (the class name is the discriminator; you can add any other condition, using, e.g., an `AndCondition`)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a [Job object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects) and [let it notify you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130405-00/?p=4743) when all processes in the Job have exited.