# process.Exited callback triggering without the actual process exiting

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, window

I have a program where I start a process and wait for it to exit like this :

```
 Process process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
 process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 process.Exited += (sender, e) =>
 {
     process.WaitForExit();
     RebootMachine();
 };
process.Start()
```

But for certain applications like "calc.exe" the the `Exited` callback has been executing immediately after the `process.Start()` has been called. I want to fix this.

I am thinking the possible reason for this is that the initial `process.Start()` starting some parent process associated with the app (but only one visible window is spawned) which inturn is starting other process and exiting immediately. Is there a way to fix/handle this case if that is the issue?

Comment: Modern Calc.exe launches another app and then exits immediately, that is why you are getting the event right away. There is nothing to fix because it is not broken, you are simply waiting on the wrong process. If you need to wait on a group of processes, then use a [Job object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects) and [let it notify you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130405-00/?p=4743) when all processes in the Job have exited.

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78020621/i-cannot-wait-for-calc-exe-to-exit-but-i-can-wait-for-mspaint-exe-to-exit-why-a

Comment: It depends on your target process precisely but something like calc will end up spawning `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator...\CalculatorApp.exe` but it's not part of your process tree, it will be launched by one of the svchost.exe ("BrokerInfrastructure"). So even with a job object you can't get to it in the calc case, you'll have to monitor processes another way.

Comment: [`AddAutomationEventHandler(UIA_Window_WindowClosedEventId,...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-howto-implement-event-handlers#handling-general-ui-automation-events) and [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--receiving-event-notifications-through-wmi-) `__InstanceDeletionEvent` both work for such notification.